# What's the mass?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, neutrinos, quarks, protons

Let's perform two simple calculations and then formulate the relative questions.

1. By checking Wikipedia, one can know the mass of neutron and proton:
   $$M_{neutron}=939.5654133(58)MeV/c^2=1.674927471(21)×10^{−27} kg$$
   $$M_{proton}=938.2720813(58) MeV/c^2=1.672621898(21)×10^{−27} kg$$
   and **the neutron (proton) is composed of two down (up) quarks and one up (down) quarks.** Also by checking Wikipedia, one can know the mass of up quark and down quark, respectively.
   $$M_{up-quark} \approx 2.3MeV/c^2 \approx 4.1 \times 10^{-30} kg \qquad M_{down-quark} \approx 4.8Mev/c^2 \approx 8.6 \times 10^{-30} kg $$
   One can see immediately that 
   $$M_{neutron} >> 2\times M_{down-quark}+1 \times M_{up-quark}$$
   $$M_{proton} >> 2\times M_{up-quark}+1 \times M_{down-quark}$$
   One can also see only one percent of the total mass of the neutron/proton is contributed by their building blocks (up- and down- quarks)!So my first question is where is the mass of neutron?
2. We can perform the similar calculations for Helium-4, **which is composed of two protons and two neutrons**. By checking Wikipedia, one can also know the mass of helium-4. But we have the following inequality:
   $$M_{helium-4}=6.645 \times 10^{-27}kg<2\times M_{proton}+2\times M_{neutron}=6.695\times 10^{-27}kg$$
   So my second question is: what's the additional mass of helium-4 atom?

My final question is about what's the difference between calculation one (far greater than their constituents )and calculation two (lesser than their constituents)?

Comment: You seem to be trying to re-discover the so-called "constituent quark model", which works reasonable well as a rough estimator of baryon masses once you extend it to more quark types and a binding contribution. But the binding contribution is important.

Comment: Have a look at this https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/ . Most of the mass of the proton and neutron come from the sea of quarks antiquarks and gluons, consequence of QCD strong interactions.